# как в laravel получить ссылку на файл?

Tags: laravel

приложение на Laravel 5.3 пользователь заливает файлы ,  как можно получить ссылку на их скачивание?

Comment: Чтобы сделать их доступными через веб, вам надо создать символьную ссылку из public/storage на storage/app/public. -> это как?

Comment: а сразу при сохранении вы их не можете двигать в папку в public ? зачем давать доступ в папку storage ?, ну или на крайний случай пользуйтесь file_get_contents в маршруте для отдачи файлов , гемор зато можно проверки сделать и отдавать контент только нужным лицам

Comment: они у меня сразу сохраняются в public/upload я еще дилетант и тупо не знаю, какой адрес писать в <a href="...">

Comment: для всего что лежит в public в шаблоне можно использовать `assets()` или `public_path()`

Comment: в папке assets у меня лежат vue-компоненты, ну и всякие стили, js-ки... по докуметации assets  нужны для подключения стилей и скриптов